# Swift Siri simple Q&A

Tags: swift, siri, sirikit

I would like to have a quite simple Siri extension where I ask something and Siri just answers for Example:
I say:
**Hey Siri what do you like in *my App*?**
Siri answers:
**I love the Siri integration!**
At the Apple website I just found things like payment or messaging apps but no simple  Q&A...
Could you give me a sample or an good Hint, where I can find something like I want?
Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with Intents Extension. From your app you add a new Intents Extension and there you create an intent response. In the response you can set whatever you want siri to answer when that intent is being triggered. Check the Soup Chef tutorial from the last WWDC if you want to learn more about it.

For convenience, here is that tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/soup_chef_accelerating_app_interactions_with_shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask Siri whatever you want and set what answer you want to get back. Check out the Intent Domains from: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit and see that there a predefined categories that it can handle.

Comment: Because of that I thought I just have to say "in my App" in the end, for Siri to trigger the Appextension...

Comment: You can  override `func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any` and handle the INIntent form SiriKit, however you will only get an intend from the category that Apple provides.